# Cauchy's theorem for integral homotopic closed curve in $G\subset\mathbb{C}^n$.

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, multivariable-calculus, integration

Recall Cauchy's theorem (third version in the Conway's book "Function of one complex variable", thm 6.7. page 90 in the second edition):

Let $f$ be an analytic function on $F\subset\mathbb{C}$ and $\gamma_0$ and $\gamma_1$ be two closed rectifiable homotopic curve curves in $F$. Then
$$\int_{\gamma_0}f=\int_{\gamma_1}f.$$

**[Edit:** As stressed in commentaries, the initial question involved integral not rigoursly defined (they don't appear anymore in this version) and the question did no make sense. I will try to put setting such that it makes sense.**]**

We consider the previous setting, with additionally $f=g'$  (the derivative of $g$), and $\gamma_j:[0,1]\to F\subset\mathbb{C}$ smooth.
The preceding integrals can be written in different ways:
$$\int_{\gamma_j}f
= \int_0^1 f(\gamma_j(t))\, \gamma'_j(t)\ dt 
= \int_0^1 g'(\gamma_j(t))\, \gamma'_j(t)\ dt 
= \int_0^1 \frac{d}{dt}g(\gamma_j(t))\ dt,$$
for $j=0,1$.
With the last form, our equation is written
$$\int_0^1 \frac{d}{dt}g(\gamma_0(t))\ dt 
=\int_0^1 \frac{d}{dt}g(\gamma_1(t))\ dt.$$

Now, it makes sense to wonder if this equality is still true when $g(z_1,\ldots,z_n)$ is an analytic function on $G\subset\mathbb{C}^n$,
and $\gamma_j:[0,1]\to G$ are smooth closed rectifiable homotopic curves in $G$, for $j=0,1$.

Comment: In the situation interesting me, $G$ is a circular domain in $\mathbb{C}^n$, *i.e.* the preimage of a domain of $\mathbb{R}^n$ under the morphism $(z_1,\ldots,z_n)\mapsto(|z_1|,\ldots,|z_n|)$.

Comment: Moreover in my situation the two curves are contained in the same compact torus $T$, where $T$ is the preimage of a fixed point by the morphism $(z_1,\ldots,z_n)\mapsto(|z_1|,\ldots,|z_n|)$.

Comment: How are you defining a holomorphic function in this case?

Comment: @CameronWilliams In the situation I am working with $f\in\mathbb{C}[X_1^{\pm1},\ldots,X_n^{\pm1}]$ a Laurent polynomial. In the general case I think we say $f$ is pluriholomorphic when it is holomorphic in each variable at every point of $G$, but I am not an expert of multivariate complex analysis.

Comment: Note that a function that is separately holomorphic (holomorphic in $z_i$ if we keep the other coordinates fixed), is holomorphic (deep enough theorem of Hartogs). But the first problem I see here is, how do you define the integral of a function over a curve? In $\mathbb{C}$, we can fudge it because we have the canonical $1$-form $dz$. What in higher dimensions, do you take $f(z)\sum dz_i$?

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks for the comment, it is true that the integrals were not correctly defined. I edited the question and turned the problem a bit differently. Do you think it makes sense now?

Comment: Okay, so if we remove the primitive $g$ of $f$, the situation is that you have an $n$-tuple $F=(f_1,\dotsc,f_n)$ of holomorphic functions, and $\int_\gamma F\cdot dz = \int_0^1 \sum\limits_{i=1}^n f_i(\gamma(t))\cdot \gamma_i'(t)\,dt$. Then the question is, if you have two homotopic closed paths $\gamma$ and $\beta$, do you have $\int_\gamma F\cdot dz = \int_\beta F\cdot dz$? I'm pretty sure the answer is that you have equality when $F$ satisfies the integrability conditions $\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial z_k} = \frac{\partial f_k}{\partial z_i}$ for all $i,k$.