# Need help verifying $\int_\gamma \left(\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{z^2}\right)dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I am supposed to compute this integral $$\int_\gamma \left(\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{z^2}\right)dz$$
along the triangle-shaped path $\gamma$ having vertices at points $2+i$,$-2+3i$ and $-1-i$.

EDIT: Fixed
Replacing the closing triangular path with unit circle:
$z(t)=e^{it}$, $dz=ie^{it}dt$ with $0 \leq t \leq 2\pi$.

Now
$$\begin{align}
\int_\gamma \left(\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{z^2}\right)dz&=\int_0^{2\pi}(e^{-it}+e^{-2it})ie^{it}dt\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}i+ie^{-it}dt\\
&=i\int_0^{2\pi}dt-\int_0^{2\pi}(-i)e^{-it}dt\\  
&=|_0^{2\pi}t-|_0^{2\pi}e^{-it}\\  
&=2\pi i-(e^{-2\pi i}-1)\\
&=2\pi i.
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your integration of $1/z$ is not correct. Read the answers to this question: [ln(z) as antiderivative of 1/z](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1154321/lnz-as-antiderivative-of-1-z)

Alternative approach. Recall the [Cauchy's integral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem). Does the given triangle-shaped closed path $\gamma$ contain in its interior the pole $z=0$ of the integrand function $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{z^2}$?

If the answer is no then $\int_\gamma f(z)dz=0$. If the answer is yes then 
$\int_\gamma f(z)dz=\int_{C} f(z)dz$ where $C$ is the unit circle $|z|=1$  oriented counterclockwise (which is easier to evaluate).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Im totally beginner with complex analysis, just read about the Cauchy's theorem. So if interior of the path $\gamma$ contains the point $z=(0,0)$, then $\int_\gamma f(z)dz=\int_{C} f(z)dz$, which is the case now i guess? Why can we use unit circle as a path?

Comment: Actually the integral is the same along any simple closed contour which contains $0$. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/485766/cauchys-theorem-for-integral-homotopic-closed-curve-in-g-subset-mathbbcn

Comment: Tried to fix it, hopefully went to right direction. If you have time to check, would appreciate :).

Comment: @Yulia23576 Now, it is correct!!